# openshift node.js save upload across gears

Tags: openshift

[openshift newb here] Using Openshift free tier though moving to silver soon if that helps. node / express 3.2.5 / multer to upload images as form-multipart.
As Openshift free tier gives 3 gears using one gear for the 'public' web app, that is, the display surfers will see; and another gear for the admin: forms etc that the content creators will have access too. Both are talking to the same mongolab mongo database.

What I'm wondering is ... can admins upload images from the admin gear with the files being saved to a public/images directory on the public gear. I've tried some not-gonna-work stuff with absolute paths etc. Checked out a few stackoverflow posts on Openshift and port binding but I'm missing something. I'd rather not implement upload with password protection on the public gear.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Amazon S3 to host your images. That's what we did to solve this issue when creating OpenShift Hub (scaled Ruby on Rails app).

Check out the [AWS Node.js Sample Project](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-nodejs-sample).

See also:

- https://hub.openshift.com/
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/openshift-hub/production/quickstarts/106/ruby.png?1425674597